# Spring URL not encoding correctly in JSP

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I have the following HTML snippet that I'm including in several pages.

```
<td><a href="<c:url value="guestBook" /> "><img src="images/guestbook.jpg" alt="Guest Book" /></a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value="polls" />"><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value="graduation" />"><img src="images/graduation.jpg" alt="Graduation" /></a></td>
<td><a href="<c:url value="home" />"><img src="images/home.jpg" alt="Home" /></a></td>
```

In all of these pages except the graduation link, this gets translated as:

```
<td><a href="guestBook "><img src="images/guestbook.jpg" alt="Guest Book" /></a></td>
<td><a href="polls"><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>
<td><a href="graduation"><img src="images/graduation.jpg" alt="Graduation" /></a></td>
<td><a href="home"><img src="images/home.jpg" alt="Home" /></a></td>
```

On the graduation page, the link is rendered as the original source code, i. e. `<a href="c:url value="...>`  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` in my code.  When I put it in, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are using double quotes inside double quotes, which is ending the double quotes.

Use single quotes instead or escape the double quotes with a backslash.

Ex 1 with single quotes.

```
<td><a href='<c:url value="polls" />'><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>
```

Ex 2 with escaped quotes.

```
<td><a href="<c:url value=\"polls\" />"><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>
```

Comment: Escaping the double quotes gave me a HTTP 500 error for all pages, and using the single quotes just game me the same error as before.

Comment: When you are using single quotes, are you replacing the single quotes for all `a` elements?

Comment: I'm currently using what you have for Ex. 1.  The HTML rendered in the browser comes out as

<td><a href='<c:url value="polls" />'><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>.

It only happens when I go to my graduation page.  In the other pages it is rendered as

<td><a href='polls'><img src="images/polls.jpg" alt="Polls" /></a></td>